# Select query result to List<int>

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have problem to do below query in Entity Framework and also equate the result to List:

```
select count(*) from user_behave_fact
where beef_dairy_stat = 'True' and param_id = 2
group by p_min,p_max
go


using (var db = new J_DBEntities())
{
    List<int> dry_icc_ctn_mm = db.user_behave_fact.Where(x => x.beef_dairy_stat == true && x.param_id == 1)
        .GroupBy(x => new {x.p_min, x.p_max}).Count();
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do this mvc.

Comment: `.Count()` returns an `int`, not a `List<int>`. Are you want the count of the items in each group?

Comment: yes i want count of each group

Comment: `.GroupBy(x => new {x.p_min, x.p_max}).Select(a => a.Count()).ToList()`

Comment: sorry im asking here if i want do casting like select cast(col1 as varchar)+'-'+(col2 as varchar) what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This instead

```
using (var db = new J_DBEntities())
{
    List<int> dry_icc_ctn_mm = db.user_behave_fact.Where(x => x.beef_dairy_stat == true && x.param_id == 1)
        .GroupBy(x => new {x.p_min, x.p_max}).Select(y=>y.Count());
}
```

Comment: sorry im asking here if i want do casting like select cast(col1 as varchar)+'-'+(col2 as varchar) what should i do?

Comment: context.Table.Select(x=>new(x.col1.ToString()+'-'+x.col2.ToString());

Comment: select should be after where and group by or before,,,,and it is () or {}

Comment: context.Table.Where(x=>someCondition).Select(x=>new{x.col1.ToString()+'-'+x.col2.ToS‌​tring()});